# Does this equality matter?

Tags: real-analysis

I encountered two seemingly different definitions of convergence in measure. I think they are the same just as there are many equivalent definitions of convergence sequence.($\leq \epsilon$ or $< \epsilon$)

But here I do not know how to check.

Suppose $f_{n}$ and $f$ are measurable functions from $(X,\Sigma, \mu) \to (\Bbb R,\Bbb B(\Bbb R))$.

The definition of convergence in measure is that $f_{n} \to f$ in measure if for every $\varepsilon>0$

1. \begin{equation}
   \mu(\{x:|f_{n}(x)-f(x)|\geq\varepsilon\})\to0 \text{ as } n\to \infty
   \end{equation}
2. \begin{equation}
   \mu(\{x:|f_{n}(x)-f(x)|>\varepsilon\})\to0 \text{ as } n\to \infty
   \end{equation}

My trying: $\mu(\{x:|f_{n}(x)-f(x)|\geq\varepsilon\})=\mu(\{x:|f_{n}(x)-f(x)|>\varepsilon\}) + \mu(\{x:|f_{n}(x)-f(x)|=\varepsilon\})$.

If 1. holds, I do not know whether the limits exist for both of the two elements of the right-hand side. (If exist, 2. holds). So I can not get 2. holds.

Comment: I still did not get your point. Can you please elaborate on it?

Comment: Notice that because $\epsilon>0$ is arbitrary, if the non-strict inequality holds for $\epsilon$, we can choose $0< \epsilon’ < \epsilon$ such that the non-strict inequality holds for $\epsilon ’$ as well. By definition, the strict inequality would then be true for $\epsilon$.

Comment: To expaned on Peder's comment, if the definition was for some particular $\epsilon$ instead of every $\epsilon$, you would be right in suspecting they might not be the same. But the definition requires the condition to hold for every $\epsilon$. (1)$\implies$(2) for any given $\epsilon$, since $>\epsilon \implies \ge\epsilon$, and (2)$\implies$(1) since for $\epsilon' < \epsilon$, (2) for $\epsilon'$ implies (1) for $\epsilon$.